# Filter in Django if template tag not working

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I have almost literally exactly what is in the django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#filters)

```
{% if things|length > 1 %}

    <div>
        <span>Multiple things were found for this search criteria</span>
        <button>Show All</button>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

And yet the div is showing up when `things|length` is 0.

I'm using Django 1.3.1, so I don't know if that's the problem-- I couldn't find that information. It wasn't in the 1.4 release notes, at least.

What the heck is going on? Is this a 1.3 problem, or...?

Edit: really looks like this was introduced in [1.2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.2/#new-in-1-2-smart-if) and should be working. So what's the deal?

Comment: is itineraries a queryset object?

Comment: could you post how you are getting itineraries?

Comment: you mean my view code? I'm literally setting `results = {itineraries=[]}`, looping over something else and appending dicts to it, and then passing results to the template.

Comment: Are you sure, that `itineraries|length` is 0? How do you pass it in a template. Btw, `results = {itineraries=[]}` has `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. Maybe you mean `results = {itineraries:[]}`

Comment: That is what I meant, thanks. `{{ itineraries|length }}` renders 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try 
{% if itineraries.items|length > 1 %}
 ...
{% endif %} or only {% if itineraries %}

Comment: I forgot that the part of the template I had this code is rendered before itineraries is passed in, so itineraries was absent (I'm assuming Django templates treats that as itineraries = None), and although `{{ itineraries|length }}` rendered 0, it must have been getting treated like `''` lower down.

Comment: apparently this is a weird design problem... http://python.6.n6.nabble.com/Django-18742-Template-tag-length-returns-invalid-value-td4984576.html